# When selecting "Not Sure" in the review section does the question get removed from review section?

Tags: support, review

It seems to me that when I select "Not Sure" when reviewing an item that the item gets removed from the review list (The number in the review section seems to decrease much faster than the number of reviews each day). 
Is this just a coincidence or does this happen? Or is this the wanted feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gets removed from your review list.  If you aren't sure about this, you can easily experiment by picking a small category and hitting "Not Sure" 5 or 6 times in a row and looking at the count go down.  And, the reasoning makes perfect sense.  If you are not sure what to do about it, there's no reason for it to stay there.  But, if you are not sure what to do about it, then someone else should look at it, so it is going to stay in the queue for others to look at.  It is simply removed from your queue.

Comment: Ah, ok. I assumed everybody had the same review list.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer I just did "Not sure" to every single question in "Close Vote" and now I have 0 in my queue.  How many are in your queue?

Comment: 16, although I have not enough reputation to review any of them :-)

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Then that proves our lists are not the same.